# Missing pdf when using \usetikzlibrary{external} in LyX

Tags: lyx, tikz-external

I'm trying to use the externalization library in LyX to speed up compilation and generate separate PDF files with each of my tikz figures. But for some reason LyX does not output a separate PDF file that only includes the figure.

Here's the tex file as exported from LyX:

```
\documentclass[12pt,english]{article}  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}  
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=3cm,bmargin=3cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm,headheight=1cm,headsep=0.8cm,footskip=1.5cm}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\setlength{\parskip}{\medskipamount}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatletter
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[] 
\tikzset{external/system call={pdflatex \tikzexternalcheckshellescape -halt-on-error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "\image" "\texsource" & convert "\image".pdf "\image".eps}}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{place}=[circle,draw=blue,fill=blue!20,line width=2pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) [place] {Ti\textit{k}Z};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Under Tools > Preferences > File Handling I changed the converter for LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex) to `pdflatex -shell-escape $$i`

When I compile on my Windows machine I only get the PDF file with the main document, it does not create a separate file with the figure and it does not speed up the compilation at all. What am I missing?

Comment: For export (i.e. not view): LyX runs everything in a temporary folder and then copies what it needs back when you export. It thinks it only needs one PDF so that's all it copies. If you want it to copy more, write a script that does that and use that instead of the `pdflatex -shell-escape $$i` command. Read Help > Customization for more information. Now for Viewing you would need to create a script and put that as your "viewer" for a certain format. That script could open several PDFs (although it would need to guess the others from the main one).

Comment: If you have access to a Linux machine, I can help you write the scripts. I don't know how to do this for Windows.

Comment: @scottkosty What if I wasn't interested in a separate PDF with the figure. Right now the compilation time doesn't improve at all from using \usetikzlibrary{external}, so it seems to me like I'm not getting the package to work properly. I was hoping there would be a way to get it to work in LyX

Comment: In that case my guess is it has nothing to do with LyX. Post the LaTeX (from File > Export > Latex) and hopefully someone can help you.

Comment: @scottkosty I updated with the full TeX code now

Comment: The code does work in TeXworks using pdfTeX+shellescape, so I guess it's got something to do with getting shellescape to work in LyX.

Comment: In that case I agree. Are you sure you edited the correct LyX converter? If you change it to jibberish does it fail?

Comment: @scottkosty It does not. I thought I needed to edit LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex). Do you have any idea which one I need to edit then?

Comment: How are you viewing/exporting? Instead of using the eyes button, use Export > PDF (pdflatex). That way you can be sure of which format you're exporting. The eyes icon tries to guess what you want and is sometimes wrong.

Comment: @scottkosty I already did. I feel like I'm missing something obvious here. I changed the converter for LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex) to jibberish and used Export > PDF (pdflatex) with no problems. Except for that it still doesn't make a separate PDF with the figure, as it does when I compile it in TeXworks.

Comment: Don't worry about the extra PDF thing. That is expected and you need a custom script to get around that. As far as the jibberish, I would recommend running LyX from the command lines and using -dbg flags to get more information. For example, try with `lyx -dbg info yourfile.lyx`. Also take a look at View > Messages

Comment: @scottkosty I can't figure out how to run it from the command lines. Also, I thought the problem is that it doesn't create the extra PDF. In the documentation for the externalization library for tikz it says "the purpose is to convert each picture to a separate pdf without changing the document as such"

Comment: From what I see, there are two goals. One is the speed of compilation. The other is the separate figures. Is that true? At this point, you don't know if it is creating the other files. All you know is LyX is only *displaying* one. Big difference. If it is working correctly, LyX is only copying one PDF from the temporary directory. In that temporary directory there might be other files that you want, but you have to tell LyX to copy them with your own converter script. To see the temp directory, compile and (without closing LyX) look in the path that you have in Preferences>Paths for tmp

Comment: @scottkosty Thanks for your help. I now got it to work and was able to find the separate figure files in a temporary directory. However, the main reason I looked at externalization was for my thesis. Here I need to use XeTex and I cannot get that to work. I replaced pdflatex with xelatex and added -shell-escape to that converter, but it doesn't speed up compilation and it doesn't create the temporary PDF files. Are there any other changes that needs to be made to get XeTex to work instead of pdflatex?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you replaced `pdflatex` with `xelatex` in the converter LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex). If so, this is incorrect. You should use the converter LaTeX (XeTeX) -> PDF (XeTeX). This way LyX knows that you want to export to LaTeX and will do a lot of the work for you. In any case, please open a new question with the tags `lyx` and `xetex` and post an example of the exported xetex code.

Comment: @scottkosty I did change the converter LaTeX (XeTeX) -> PDF (XeTeX). After I added prefix=Figures/ as argument to \tikzexternalize in the preamble, it's working. I don't know why. But many thanks for your help!

Comment: glad to hear it's working now! You should post your solution and accept it (for archival purposes and so everyone knows that this question is answered).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code posted in the question actually did work. The tricky part in LyX is that LyX converts each picture to a separate PDF that it saves in a temporary directory as scottkosty pointed out to me. The path of this folder can be found under Tools > Preferences > Paths. The files can easily be copied and saved in other directories.

When using pdflatex to compile the conveter LaTeX (pdflatex) -> PDF (pdflatex) needs to be changed under Tools > Preferences > File Handling to `pdflatex -shell-escape $$i`.

When using XeTeX the converter LaTeX (XeTeX) -> PDF (XeTeX) needs to be changed to `xelatex -shell-escape $$i`. I also had to pass a subdirectory to tikzexternalize in the preample, e.g. `\tikzexternalize[prefix=Figures/]`.